# On open Gromov-Witten invariants of the projective line

Tags: resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, integrable-systems

I'm a mathematician interested in mathematical physics, but, again, penetrating the physics literature is not so easy for me.

In the mathematical literature, a lot has been written about closed GW-invariants, opposed to open ones, at least as far as I understand. For example, the closed GW-invariants of the point resp. the projective space $\mathbb P ^1$ are well-known due to Witten-Kontsevich resp. Okounkov-Pandharipande (and many others). Recently, Pandharipande, Solomon and Tessler have initiated a mathematical (sound) framework for the study of open GW-invariants of the point (roughly, by constructing an intersection theory on moduli spaces of bordered Riemann surfaces).

**I'd like to know** any references concerning open analogues of the work of Okounkov and Pandharipande, i.e., open GW-invariants for $\mathbb P ^1$. This should be well known to physicists at least, but I couldn't find any literature (except for open GW invariants for 3 CYs).

Answer (score 2):

The open Gromov-Witten invariants for $\mathbb{P}^1$ were computed by Hori in 'Linear Models of Supersymmetric D-branes' (http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0012179), using both direct computation via the nonlinear sigma model (NLSM) with target space $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, as well as computation via the mirror Landau-Ginzburg model which is dual to this NLSM. His mirror computation can also be generalized to the case where $X$ is a toric manifold with semipositive-definite first Chern class.

Additional details are contained in Chapter 39 of the 'Mirror Symmetry' monograph by Hori et al.